# How to check the Base signature for all objects?

Tags: community

The base signature for the standard object is given below:

Here are the standard field names:

Object | Lookup Field | Base Signature | Coding for ID | Coding for Name

Leads | Campaign | lea20 | lea20_lkid | lea20_lkold

Contacts | Reports to | Con8 | con8_lkid | con8_lkold
Contacts | Account | Con4 | con4_lkid | con4_lkold

Account | Parent Account | Acc3 | acc3_lkid | acc3_lkold

Opportunities | Account | Opp4 | opp4_lkid | opp4_lkold
Opportunities | Campaign Source | Opp17 | opp17_lkid | opp17_lkold

Contracts | Account | Ctrc7 | ctrc7_lkid | ctrc7_lkold

Cases | Contact | Cas3 | cas3_lkid | cas3_lkold

Would like to know the Base signature for Tasks